# PL/SQL Query for column and use it in the function call

Tags: plsql

I am trying this but sure I am missing a lot

```
declare 
  my_id table.ISR_ID%type; 
begin
  select NVL(MAX(table.ISR_ID)+1,1) into isr_id
    from table; 

  select my_pkg.getFunction(InputToFunction=> isr_id);  -- from ?
end;
```

Comment: Your code is written to expect a variable named `isr_id`, but you have only created a variable named `my_id`. Should the references to a variable named `isr_id` actually be to `my_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declared MY_ID variable, you should have selected into it, not into ISR_ID (which is never declared).

Also, you should return function's result into *something* (probably another variable?). I've declared it as FUN_RES - see the comment within the PL/SQL anonymous block.

Saying that you are missing a lot doesn't help much; you should specify which errors you get. Anyway: try such a code, say whether it works or not and - if not - say *why not* (possible errors, etc.).

```
declare 
  my_id   table.ISR_ID%type; 
  fun_res number;       --> function result should be returned into this variable.
                        --  I don't know what it returns, so I set it to be a NUMBER.
                        --  Change it, if necessary.
begin  
  select NVL(MAX(table.ISR_ID) + 1, 1) 
    into my_id 
    from table; 

  fun_res := my_pkg.getFunction(my_id);  
end;
```

**[EDIT]**

If you have to select function's value for every ISR_ID in a table, then you don't need PL/SQL but

```
select isr_id, 
       my_pkg.getfunction(isr_id) fun_res
from table;
```

If you want PL/SQL, then do it in a loop, for example:

```
begin
  for cur_r in (select isr_id from table) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.isr_id ||', result = ' || my_pkg.getfunction(cur_r.isr_id));
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Thank you. The function returns 0 or 1 (number is good for me). My follow up question is does this line - select NVL(MAX(table.ISR_ID) + 1, 1) - includes all of the column values and the function does check for all the values ? meaning if I do -  select count(distinct ISR_ID) from table - I get count of 1million.

Comment: If there's no WHERE clause, it'll select maximum value of all ISR_IDs in that table.

Comment: Oh ok.. Actuall I need to have the function run for every ISR_ID i have in the table